# Is there a reason why java does not have a class which allows both reading String and byte [] from a stream?

Tags: java, http, stream

Is there a reason why java does not have a class which allows both reading String and byte [] from a stream and also another for writing String and byte [] to a stream? What if it is necessary to transfer both byte [] and String like in HTTP?

Comment: @mfrankli Mutually convertible? Yes. Interchangeable? Hardly. A `byte[]` only makes sense as a character string if you know what encoding to interpret it with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would likely be potential issues with character encodings. In particular, Java internally represents strings in UTF-16, which probably isn't what, say, someone on the other end of a network connection is expecting. The resulting behavior would be consistent, but not necessarily what the average programmer would expect.

Getting a `byte[]` representation of a String isn't hard. Just use [`String.getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29), or the overloaded version which allows you to specify the encoding.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html is a great resource on encoding issues

Comment: I actually remembered that, and don't know why I didn't link to it. Thanks!

Comment: What about reading a line from a byte inputstream(delimiter is CRLF)? Is there a faster way of doing it instead of reading byte by byte from a stream and comparing the previous char and the current char?

Comment: You really have to do that no matter what; it's just that some stream classes hide it under the covers for you. You can, of course, write your own class that does this.

Answer (score 1):

It does. `DataInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` both have both: readLine() and readUTF() for Strings, and read(byte[],...) for bytes.

Comment: @shawn it is indeed, but it also exists. The premiss of your question is false.